# Подскажите как можно считать данные с бекенда и отобразить эти данные в таблице?

Tags: javascript

Задача стоит в том, что необходимо создать CRUD интерфейс на React для готового бекенда. Я сделал компонент для отображения таблицы и теперь необходимо считать данные и отразить их в этой таблице.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

axios - библиотека для удобных ajax запросов. Можно использовать нативный fetch.
https://github.com/axios/axios. Компонента Table - это ваша кастомная компонента.
Как у ваз реализованы данные в API неизвестно, поэтому отрендерите как вам удобно.

Идея следующая:
 1. После того как прогрузилась компонента `(componentDidMount)` - вытягиваете данные с бэкенда и записывайте их в локальный `state` компонента.
 2. Далее пробрасываете данные в компонент и рендерите как вам удобно.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await axios.get('api');
    this.setState({ data })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table data={this.state.data} />
    )
  }
}
```